# Decision to not speak on confidential matters

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word:

> I discussed certain confidential matters with my client. She relied on my __ in not speaking of them.

There's a word specifically for this situation, better than "restraint" and essentially opposite to "openness".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*[Discretion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discretion)* is probably what you are looking for here (meaning 2, or meaning 1 [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discretion)).

Answer (score 10):

You could use  *discretion* here:

### [discretion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discretion)

> : the quality of having or showing discernment or good judgment : the quality of being discreet

- She relied on my *confidence* in not speaking of them.
- She relied on my *discretion* in not speaking of them.

Comment: *Confidence* is wrong here: it's the *client* who has confidence (in the speaker's discretion).

Comment: ruakh is correct. She told you _in_ confidence, trusting your discretion.